# wp_mail function not working in live server (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

This is the code which I am using to send mail in wordpress using wp_mail function, its working fine in local host since I enabled smtp with port number 25, username and password.

But In live server I have an issue its not sending the mail,
I tried installing a Postman SMTP Mailer/Email Log plugin and the test mail works fine through that plugin page, still I am not able to receive mail when go to my webpage and submit the form.

Any Idea.?

```html
function do_send_message() {
  if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) &&isset($_POST['message']) &&isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name']; $email = $_POST['email']; $message = $_POST['message']; $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $to = "jamesmathew870@gmail.com";
    $subject = "General Enquiry";
       $body = "\n\nName: $name \n\nphone: $phone \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $message";
     $headers = "From:  <$email>" . "\r\n";
    $success = wp_mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
            if ($success) return true;        
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_message', 'do_send_message' );
```

Comment: does your wordpress sends any other email such as password reset.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigures the wp_mail() function to use SMTP instead of mail() and creates an options page to manage the settings.Please check by seding a test email.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/